# Is there any java function act like 'LIKE' statement in SQL?

Tags: java, sql-like

I want to find a function in java that can check if string contain pattern "%A%B%" just like 'LIKE' statement in SQL. This function will return true if the string contain the pattern and false if not.

Can anyone suggest any class, function or line of code? Thank you!

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: Regular expression: put `.*` instead of `%` and `.` instead of `_`

Comment: What do '.' and '*' mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression. Learn more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

The easiest way of calling it is using [`String.matches(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

If you want to check the same regular expression more often, it's better to precompile it and use a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

A typical invocation sequence is then

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*A.*B.*"); // you keep this stored for re-use
 Matcher m = p.matcher("BARBARIAN");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

There is a good [Online Regex Tester and Debugger](https://regex101.com/) tool, where you can check your regular expression.

Comment: The regex suggested here doesn't match the same things as `LIKE "%A%B%"`. For example, it won't match "BARBARIAN", whereas the SQL expression would.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile(".*A.*B.*").matches(input)
```

will return true if `input` contains an A followed by a B.